# How to pass data and aesthetics across ggplot2 functions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to create a figure with ggplot2 that has roughly this structure:

```
p <- ggplot() +
        geom_rect(data = regions,aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), 
                  fill = "yellow",alpha = 0.1) + 
    geom_line(data = data, aes(x=dt, y = y, color = case))  +
    geom_point(data = data, aes(x=dt, y = y, color = case)) +
    facet_grid(groups ~ ., scale="free_y")
    geom_vline(x=as.numeric(dates_start), color = "orange3",linetype="dashed") + 
    geom_vline(x=as.numeric(dates_end), color = "orange3",linetype="dashed")

p
```

Is there anyway I can avoid having to pass all the details in `geom_point`? since they are the same as the one used in `geom_line`?

Comment: You could do it in the general ggplot() (so that would be `ggplot(data = data, aes(x=dt, y = y, color = case)) + geom_line()+geom_point()`)

Comment: @Heroka thanks, but for some reason when I use geom_rect() that doesn't work and throws an error. I usually do the way you propose, but I had to change it this time.

Comment: I don't know why that is, hard to say without seeing what the data looks like.